# Why are underscores converted to directory separators in PSR-0?

Tags: php, standards, psr-0

I'm trying to figure out why would underscores in class names be converted to directory separators in [PSR-0](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-0/)? I'm sure there is a reason for it, but I can't think of why.

If I have a class named `my_class_name` in the namespace `\namespace\subnamespace`
Wouldn't that then convert to `\namespace\subnamespace\my\class\name` when what I want is `\namespace\subnamespace\my_class_name`?
I understand if my class system is built around this it would work, but if I wanted directory separators I would have just used a backslash instead of an underscore.

Comment: In general you shouldn't be using underscores in class name. Camel case is preferred.

Comment: I personally don't, but I'm using a PSR-0 compatible auto-loader but have to use a set of classes I did not create (which contains underscores in the class names).  Particularly https://github.com/Setasign/FPDI.  I know they have a composer.json file which would solve my problems, but my system does not run composer (which is another issue in itself but that is for another day).  That is besides the point though.  I'm really just asking why would something like this be included in PSR-0?

Comment: Note that PSR-4 autoloading does not convert underscores to directory separators.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because history. It was common prior to PHP gaining namespace support for projects to use underscore-separated bits for a sort of poor man's namespacing. There was enough of that still going on at the time PSR-0 was created to make it a practical decision.

Comment: Good enough answer for me.  I suppose my only options are to use composer, add hardcoded logic to my autoloader, or try to modify the classes to eliminate the underscores.  I don't know if the last is technically legal, so I probably won't take that route.

Comment: I also saw this poor man's namespacing pattern in [other languages](https://github.com/grayj/Jedi-Outcast/blob/85f58467344d3ccbc6e2501a9af573ff4488a898/utils/Radiant/Quake3/pmesh.cpp#L4052). I wonder what's it's called...